# array_replace_recursive does not replace an array with some empty array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got the problem. Here is my code:

```
$a = ['elm1' => 1, 'elm2' => []];
$b = ['elm1' => 2, 'elm2' => [3]];
$c = array_replace_recursive($b, $a);
```

In $c I expect to see **['elm1' => 1, 'elm2' => []]**, however I get **['elm1' => 1, 'elm2' => [3]]**. It does not replace **'elm2' => [3]** with **'elm2' => []**.

Is this some kind of feature or this is a bug in array_replace_recursive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_merge()`:-

```
<?php

$a = ['elm1' => 1, 'elm2' => []];
$b = ['elm1' => 2, 'elm2' => [3]];
$c = array_merge($b,$a); //it will check the indexes in both array and if indexes are same then first array value will remain on that index second will replace. 

echo "<pre/>";print_r($c);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/395368

Comment: `array_merge` will replace all the values for a corresponding `key` of sub-array while `array_replace_recursive` replace only the `key`s which match, rest remain same..

Comment: `array_merge` will work over here but the OP need `array_replace` instead @b0s3 @anantkumarsingh you need to explain why `array_merge` you have used too

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`array_replace_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) you need simple [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) as

```
$a = ['elm1' => 1, 'elm2' => []];
$b = ['elm1' => 2, 'elm2' => [3]];
$c = array_replace($b, $a);
print_r($c);//['elm1' => 1, 'elm2' => []]
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/395385)

Comment: But you are using `array_replace_recursive`.

Comment: I think anant have to explain the above answer @b0s3