# php array replace recursive does not update key with empty array

Tags: php

`array_replace_recursive` not updating second level key of array with empty array, below is the code

```
$base = ['elm1' => 'Foo', 'elm2' => ['subElm1' => 'bar', 'subElm2' => ['a','b']]];
$replacement = ['elm2' => ['subElm2' => []]];
$result = array_replace_recursive($base, $replacement);
print_r($result);
```

Output is:

```
Array ( [elm1] => Foo [elm2] => Array ( [subElm1] => bar [subElm2] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b ) ) )
```

Expected output:

```
Array ( [elm1] => Foo [elm2] => Array ( [subElm1] => bar [subElm2] => Array ( ) ) )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312042/array-replace-recursive-does-not-replace-an-array-with-some-empty-array

Comment: @JayeshDhandha if I use methods from link, which are array_merge or array_replace then whole data in that key will be update and i will lose data, like in above example I will lose 'subElm1' data

Comment: I think you should override the existing array element instead of using recursive mechanism. It will make you manipulation more easy.` foreach($array as &$value){    if($value['arr_key'] === 'arr_value'){$value['Value'] = "Test Value; break; // Stop the loop after we've found the item}}`

Answer (score 1):

[manual for array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive) states:

> When the value in array1 is scalar, it will be replaced by the value in array2, may it be scalar or array. When the value in array1 and array2 are both arrays, array_replace_recursive() will replace their respective value recursively.

now, when it comes to subElm2 - which both are arrays - it will replace recursively ... so:

```
[0=>'a', 1=>'b']    and    []
```

now, since the second array doesn't contain any elements, no replacement occurs. Happy times. if the second array was just `null` it would overwrite.

`array_replace_recursive` doesn't know when to stop. if faced with two arrays to replace, it has to recurse ;o)